# Extract all JSON keys from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have a JSON column properties like:

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 5}
{'c': 3, 'a': 5}
{'d': 1, 'c': 7}
{'e': 1, 'f': 7}
```

How can I get all distinct (top-level) key names from MySQL?

Like this:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Thank You!

Comment: My suggestion: Either format your data better in your database, or switch to a DBMS such as PostgreSQL that can handle json columns a lot more efficiently (Which include pivoting multiple columns into separate rows).

Comment: Read this: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-json/

Pointing you to the right direction.

Comment: @FrankerZ This is one-time issue ...

Answer (score 8):

test_tbl:

```
+----+------------------+
| id | json_col         |
+----+------------------+
|  2 | {"a": 2, "b": 5} |
|  3 | {"c": 3, "a": 5} |
|  4 | {"d": 1, "c": 7} |
|  5 | {"e": 1, "f": 7} |
+----+------------------+
```

Using [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) in Mysql 8.0:

```
SELECT DISTINCT json_key FROM test_tbl,
    json_table(
        json_keys(json_col),
        '$[*]' COLUMNS(json_key JSON PATH '$')
    ) t;
```

Results:

```
+----------+
| json_key |
+----------+
| a        |
| b        |
| c        |
| d        |
| e        |
| f        |
+----------+
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! Is there a way to see the value type as well as second column?

Answer (score 1):

Well, not the best solution but works for `json` data type

```
select distinct(json_extract(json_keys(*YOUR_VALUE*),'$[0]')) from *YOUR_TABLE*
union
select distinct(json_extract(json_keys(*YOUR_VALUE*),'$[1]')) from *YOUR_TABLE*
```

Answer (score -1):

Start with JSON_KEYS to get the keys.  From there you have some choices but probably the best would be JSON_ARRAY.