# MySQL: Extract all Keys from a nested JSON String

Tags: mysql, json

In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67899222/9748823) is it possible to extract nested keys in a simple way?
Example:

```
{
  "a": value,
  "b": {
    "c": value
    "d": {
      "e": value
   } 
  }
}
```

Expected output: ['a', 'b.c', 'b.d.e']
What I have tried:

```
 SELECT 
 f.`id` AS `field_name`
 
 FROM table t,
    JSON_TABLE(
         JSON_KEYS(t.`column`, '$.b'),
         '$[*]' COLUMNS(
           `id` VARCHAR(191) PATH '$'
         )
     ) AS t
```

but that would only show me one of the nested keys and skip the outer

Comment: I think you might need a recursive CTE to do this. It will be easier in a real programming language, then you can write a recursive function.

Comment: *Example* - invalid JSON. *Expected output* - invalid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> SELECT JSON_SEARCH(val, 'all', 'value') result
> FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> | result                      |
> | :-------------------------- |
> | ["$.a", "$.b.c", "$.b.d.e"] |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=82b2a36f5caca2d4eebca2c499614aae)*