MariaDB SQL Query to extract json data as columns and rows
I have JSON data stored in MariaDB in a column having data type as TEXT.
Examples of 4 rows in JSON_Column of table My_Table are:
Table Row 1:
[New Values: {PSTN=0/34/25}] [Old Values: {PSTN=0/31/25/0}]
Table Row 2:
[New Values: {PASSWORD=194aa6c17f4ad64f8a38a44cb2c90c63, METHOD=7}] [Old Values: {PASSWORD=626dd7a54f2gfd7834aabbccaabb345ccb, METHOD=0}]
Table Row 3:
[New Values: {STATUS=0}] [Old Values: {STATUS=1}]
Table Row 4:
[New Values: {GROUP=223}] [Old Values: {GROUP=263}]
I am looking for solution to convert this JSON data as rows and columns as below:

Helping to provide expert solution will be highly appreciated.
Thanks and Regards

{PSTN=0/34/25} is not JSON. JSON would be {"PSTN": "0/34/25"}

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856120/extract-all-json-keys-from-mysql for how you can extract keys from JSON. You should be able to build on that for your solution.

That ain't JSON as others pointed out.
You may parse these using regex.
They have all the format {<key>=<value}.
We can create a regex that parse the key-value pairs ;
Like this :
SELECT
REGEXP_REPLACE(`new`, '\\{(.*)=(.*)\\}', '$1') as attribute, -- Attribute is the key, $1 is the key
REGEXP_REPLACE(`new`, '\\{(.*)=(.*)\\}', '$2') as new, -- $2 is the value
REGEXP_REPLACE(`old`, '\\{(.*)=(.*)\\}', '$2') as old
FROM table;

Expected output (with your first row) :



attribute
new
old




PSTN
0/34/25
0/31/25/0



